# need the unique object with the last index with it from the following array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
[{
    "Screen Size": [{
        "name": "15 inch - 15.9 inch",
        "filter": "200067-200324",
        "isChecked": true
    }]
}, {
    "Type": [{
        "name": "Ultrabook",
        "filter": "200060-200289",
        "isChecked": true,
   
    }, {
        "name": "Notebook",
        "filter": "200060-200290",
        "isChecked": true,
     
    }]
}, {
    "Type": [{
        "name": "Laptop",
        "filter": "200060-200288",
        "isChecked": true,
     
    }, {
        "name": "Ultrabook",
        "filter": "200060-200289",
        "isChecked": true,

    }, {
        "name": "Notebook",
        "filter": "200060-200290",
        "isChecked": true,
 
    }]
}, {
    "Brand": [{
        "name": "HP",
        "filter": "200140-200886",
        "isChecked": true,
    
    }, {
        "name": "Lenovo",
        "filter": "200140-200887",
        "isChecked": true,

    }]
}, {
    "Brand": [{
        "name": "HP",
        "filter": "200140-200886",
        "isChecked": true,

    }, {
        "name": "Lenovo",
        "filter": "200140-200887",
        "isChecked": true,
    }, {
        "name": "Dell",
        "filter": "200140-200888",
        "isChecked": true,

    }]
}]
```

from the above array of objects, I want to filter the unique keys one with the largest index number.

e.g. from the brand, I want the last one as it will have a higher index number.

and I'll be merging those arrays of the object, soo that I get only a single array with its internal object

expected output

```
[{
    "name": "15 inch - 15.9 inch",
    "filter": "200067-200324",
    "isChecked": true
}, {
    "name": "Notebook",
    "filter": "200060-200290",
    "isChecked": true,
}, {
    "name": "Dell",
    "filter": "200140-200888",
    "isChecked": true,
}]
```

Comment: please add your attempt. what does not work? please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: i want result from above array as 

``[{
        "name": "15 inch - 15.9 inch",
        "filter": "200067-200324",
        "isChecked": true
    },
{
        "name": "Notebook",
        "filter": "200060-200290",
        "isChecked": true,
    },
 {
        "name": "Dell",
        "filter": "200140-200888",
        "isChecked": true,

    }
]``

Comment: expected output in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `reduce()` call, fetching the first (only?) property of each object to hash the results by in the accumulator, and then iterating over the value arrays checking for larger `filter` properties.

```js
const
  output = input.reduce((a, o) => {
    let k = Object.keys(o)[0];
    o[k].forEach(e => {
      if ((a[k] ??= { ...e }).filter < e.filter) {
        a[k] = { ...e };
      }
    });
    return a;
  }, {});

console.log(output); // Output is an object with each category as property.
console.log(Object.values(output)); // or Array from Object.values()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
const input = [{ "Screen Size": [{ "name": "15 inch - 15.9 inch", "filter": "200067-200324", "isChecked": true }] }, { "Type": [{ "name": "Ultrabook", "filter": "200060-200289", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Notebook", "filter": "200060-200290", "isChecked": true, }] }, { "Type": [{ "name": "Laptop", "filter": "200060-200288", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Ultrabook", "filter": "200060-200289", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Notebook", "filter": "200060-200290", "isChecked": true, }] }, { "Brand": [{ "name": "HP", "filter": "200140-200886", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Lenovo", "filter": "200140-200887", "isChecked": true, }] }, { "Brand": [{ "name": "HP", "filter": "200140-200886", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Lenovo", "filter": "200140-200887", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Dell", "filter": "200140-200888", "isChecked": true, }] }]
</script>
```

---

If your top-level objects will have more than one property you will need to iterate over each entry instead of just retrieving the first property.

```
const input = [
  {
    "Screen Size": [],
    "Type": [],
    "Brand": []
  }, {
    "Type": [],
    "Brand": []
  }
];
```

```js
const
  output = input.reduce((a, o) => {
    Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      v.forEach(e => {
        if ((a[k] ??= { ...e }).filter < e.filter) {
          a[k] = { ...e };
        }
      });
    });
    return a;
  }, {});

console.log(output); // Output is an object with each category as property.
console.log(Object.values(output)); // or Array from Object.values()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
const input = [{ "Screen Size": [{ "name": "15 inch - 15.9 inch", "filter": "200067-200324", "isChecked": true }], "Type": [{ "name": "Ultrabook", "filter": "200060-200289", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Notebook", "filter": "200060-200290", "isChecked": true, }], "Brand": [{ "name": "HP", "filter": "200140-200886", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Lenovo", "filter": "200140-200887", "isChecked": true, }] }, { "Type": [{ "name": "Laptop", "filter": "200060-200288", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Ultrabook", "filter": "200060-200289", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Notebook", "filter": "200060-200290", "isChecked": true, }], "Brand": [{ "name": "HP", "filter": "200140-200886", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Lenovo", "filter": "200140-200887", "isChecked": true, }, { "name": "Dell", "filter": "200140-200888", "isChecked": true, }] }]
</script>
```